# How to get information about wireless net_devices

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am working in Linux kernel module which is using `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` hook. In that hook I need to know the status of all my net_devices, specially wireless devices. I am able get some information about devices from `net_device->flags` i.e `IFF_UP` is device up or down. But I need some more detail about the wireless `net_device`.

1. Is net_device wireless / wired?
2. Is wireless devices connected to wireless access point?
3. If yes which wireless access point (name of access point)?
4. Gateway address associated with that device (I think, I need to get this from routing table?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(net_device->ieee80211_ptr != NULL)`?   The `ieee80211_ptr` is a [`struct wireless_dev*`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=include/net/cfg80211.h;hb=HEAD).  This structure should give you access to most of the values you requested. In `struct wireless_dev` is `struct wiphy *wiphy;`, you can use this to get a [`cfg80211_registered_device`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=net/wireless/core.h;hb=HEAD) with `wiphy_to_dev()`.

The *gateway* address is unrelated to wireless.  I doubt `devices` have any *gateway* information but you need the interface `name` in `net_device` to find the route.  The route is *IP* related and has nothing to do with a `device`.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I am able to get the cfg80211_registered_device. But still struggling to get the connection status and name of connected `Access Point`

Comment: `cfg80211_conn` has this *AP name* via `cfg80211_connect_params` in `wireless_dev`.  I don't see an elegant way to get this information.  The `cfg80211_conn` pointer itself indicates a connection.

Comment: Actually I am receiving packets from `wired` network (in my case 'eth0') and redirecting packets on available and connected wireless network(s).

Comment: Sorry.  Missed `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING`.

Answer (score 1):

See iwconfig, iwlist, and other utilities.

Comment: I need this information in kernel module, specifically in "NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING" hook.